# ''Value of type 'AuthDataResult?' has no member 'uid'''

Tags: swift

```
@IBAction func SignUpBtn_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {

Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion:  { (user: AuthDataResult?, error:Error?) in
    if error != nil{
        print(error?.localizedDescription)
        return

}

let ref = Database.database().reference()
let usersRenfence = ref.child("users")

let uid = user.uid 
//(HERE IS WRONG, I DONT KNOW WHAT SHOULD I DO. It's my first time study code.)
let newUserRefernce = ref.child(uid)
newUserRefernce.setValue{["username": self.usernameTextField.text!, "email": self.emailTextField.text!]

print("description: \(newUserRefernce.description())")
```

Comment: let uid = user.uid  here was wrong

Comment: @carpsen90 if you’re going to edit, please edit properly

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
let uid = user.uid
```

with

```
let uid = user!.user.uid
```

Look here in [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AuthDataResult)

Comment: I tried and it shows "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'User'"